# Unwrap an Optional only if it is present

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

So currently I have

```
String uri = website.getUri();
Optional<PageDetail> pageDetail = webClient.getDetailOfUri(uri);
String displayName;
String description;
if (pageDetail.isPresent()) {
    displayName = pageDetail.get().getName();
    description = pageDetail.get().getDescription();
} else {
    displayName = uri;
    description = "";
}
```

I am calling the `getDetailOfUri(uri)` method, which returns an `Optional<PageDetail>`, and I would like to set the strings `displayName` and `description` to the values of the `PageDetail` object's fields, if it is present. Otherwise, I would like to set it to some default values.

My question is, is there a better way to rewrite this? My current code seems a bit long and tedious, and I would like to know if there is a more concise way of doing this.

Comment: besides using "bool ? ifTrue : ifFalse" I don't see it

Comment: Yeah the ternary statement isn't an option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could write:

```
String uri = website.getUri();
Optional<PageDetail> pageDetail = webClient.getDetailOfUri(uri);
String displayName = pageDetail.map(PageDetail::getName).orElse(uri);
String description = pageDetail.map(PageDetail::getDescription).orElse("");
```

If the [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) is not set, [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) will return the same unset `Optional`. Otherwise, it will map it to an `Optional` containing the result of `getName()`. Then we can use [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to return a default value when the `Optional` is unset.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still very new to Java 8's lamdas, so I'm taking a while to wrap my ahead around this. But this looks like what I need!

Comment: @Andreas my `getName()`/`PageDetail` isn't final, but `p` is guaranteed not to be a subclass of `PageDetail. So this should still work, right?

Comment: I don't like this answer because if PageDetail has more than 2 fields (displayName and description), you'll have lots of map().orElse calls. I prefer having a fallback instance and work with an non-Optional instance from there.

Comment: @pyb This assumes you actually can create a fallback instance. What if `PageDetail` is an interface?

Comment: @Tunaki you can still create an instance implementing the interface using an anonymous class.

Comment: @pyb Yes but it becomes quite tedious and it is then probably easier to have a `if`.

Comment: @Tunaki I prefer encapsulating the "Fallback/empty PageDetail" in an (anonymous or not) class so I can reuse it. I actually think the code maintenance would get more tedious with your way: as soon as you need to make new calls to `webClient.getDetailOfUri(uri)` or handle new `Optional<PageDetail>` in your codebase, you'll duplicate this code.

Comment: @pyb I think the `map().orElse()` combination is better than "empty object" for two reasons: 1) It's the `Optional` version of the `?:` operator, so easy to understand. 2) You may not know the "else" value up front. Different paths in the following code may need different fall-back values. --- But that doesn't mean that "empty object" isn't the right answer, depending on context.

Comment: @Holger My bad. Deleted comment.

Comment: @Andreas 1) I find orElseGet easier to read than map() which has nothing to do with Java's Map interface, so I guess it's a matter of preference. 2) I agree, but I don't see how the map().orElse() solves it differently. Overall I feel this violates the Single Responsibility principle.

Answer (score 9):

Use [Optional#orElseGet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) that takes a [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html):

```java
// Reference to the constructor, but you could use a Factory, etc.
// All you need is a method that returns a PageDetail
// See the Javadoc and http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-8-consumer-and-supplier
Supplier<PageDetail> emptySupplier = PageDetail::new;

pageDetail = pageDetail.orElseGet(emptySupplier);
// works the same
//pageDetail = pageDetail.orElseGet(() -> new PageDetail());

String displayname = pageDetail.getName();
String uri = pageDetail.getUri();
```

`orElseGet` will create an empty PageDetail only if the Optional has a null value. This keeps your code resource efficient.

Editable/compilable sample : https://ideone.com/9h1Ntg

**Edit:** Thanks everybody for the feedback! I was actually adding `orElseGet` which I find better. I also fixed the code to unwrap the `Optional` so `pageDetail` ends being an actual `PageDetail` instance.

**Edit 2:** Added different syntax example and editable/compilable example.

Comment: orElse(T other), not orElseGet(Supplier<T> other)

Comment: @Tunaki, I am not understanding your comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: @pyb yeah the empty PageDetail creation would be resource intensive.

Comment: @leoger The OP wants `displayName = pageDetail.get().getName();`. This code will not even compile since it is assigning a type `PageDetail` to `String`

Comment: This code assumes there is a constructor `PageDetail empty = new PageDetail(uri, "");`. This is probably not the case.

Comment: Updated answer with a Supplier.