# Optional ifPresent Return another type

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

With java 8 Optional, 
Is there a way to write this line of code:

```
Bar bar = fooOpt.isPresent() ? new Bar(fooOpt.get().getX()) : null;
```

something like:

```
Bar bar = fooOpt.ifPresent(f -> new Bar(f.getX()), null)
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277465/unwrap-an-optional-only-if-it-is-present

Comment: `ifPresent` takes as an argument and executes a `Consumer` so it only consumes value from `Optional` and it can not return anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for:

```
    Optional<Foo> fooOpt = ...
    Bar bar = fooOpt.map(foo -> new Bar(foo.getX()))
                    .orElse(null);
```

Given:

```
public class Foo {
    Object getX() {
        ...
    }
}

public class Bar {

    public Bar(Object x) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that will do. Thanks.